# Angular - How to use arrow functions with arguments?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a angular 4 app, and i'm trying to write a queue of actions. each action will be fired after the previous function finished and will get its parameters.

```js
public activeRegistrationAndSync() {
    let actionsToPerformByOrder = [
       () => this.registrationComponent.activeFormValidators.apply(null, arguments),
       () => this.registrationComponent.register.apply(null, arguments),
       () => this.autoLogin.apply(null, arguments),
       () => this.postLogin.apply(null, arguments),
       () => this.checkout.apply(null, arguments)
    ];

    let defer = new Deferred<void>();
    let curPromise = defer.promise;

    //Build chain of acitons
    actionsToPerformByOrder.forEach(action => {
      curPromise = curPromise
        .then(action)
        .catch(err => this.error.emit(err));
    })

    //Active actions
    defer.resolve();
 }
 
 
 export class Deferred<T> {
  promise: Promise<T>;
  resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
  reject:  (reason?: any) => void;

  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject  = reject;
    });
  }
}
```

My problem is that arrow functions doesn't support arguments and using function() {} instead change the this reference.

Comment: "Doesn't support arguments"? `(argument) => { ... }`

Comment: arrow functions do support arguments: `(arg1, arg2) => this.doSomethingWith(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: If you really need to use `function() { ... }` instead, you can define `let that = this;` before, and use `that` in the `functions` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `async/await` to combine and run your actions. It's easy to read, here is the basic idea, modify it with your specific case:

```
async function activeRegistrationASync() {
  const actionsToPerformByOrder = [
    async (r) => {
      return Promise.resolve(3)
    },
    async (r) => {
      return Promise.resolve(r + 5)
    }
  ];

  let result;
  for (let action of actionsToPerformByOrder) {
    result = await action(result);
  }
  return result;
}

activeRegistrationASync().then((r) => {
  console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: Can I chain the result of one function as the parameter of the next one without the need to know what each function should receive?
I know it can be done using apply(null, arguments) but arguments doesn't work with arrow functions. I want to write a class that will build a queue of executable functions which each function result will be supplied as parameter to the next function.

Comment: but that is exactly what I'm doing, I'm passing the result of one function to the next. _without the need to know what each function should receive_ - what do you mean here?

Comment: Yes . Thank you very much :-) I used what you wrote to build a actionsQueue class with addAction and execute functions

Comment: @user3554268, great, consider accepting my answer then)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use spread operator like

   (...rest) => console.log(rest)
2. You can use `bind` function

   function func (/*arguments*/) {console.log(this. arguments)}

   let a = func.bind(this)